# How to efficiently insert an array as nested set model with Laravel/PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nested-sets

I am using this package to handle hierarchy data in Laravel: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Their is an implemented functionality which provides the opportunity to `create` new data with a multidimensional array. So I have the following sample array (of a file/directory hierarchy):

```
array:3 [
  "name" => "Folder1"
  "type" => "folder"
  "children" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "name" => "test1.txt"
      "type" => "txt"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "name" => "Folder1.1"
      "type" => "folder"
      "children" => array:2 [
        0 => array:2 [
          "name" => "file.png"
          "type" => "png"
        ]
        1 => array:3 [
          "name" => "folder1.1.1"
          "type" => "folder"
          "children" => array:1 [
            0 => array:2 [
              "name" => "file.txt"
              "type" => "txt"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

But their are directories with more than 10GB of data which means they have a much higher complexity than the shown example with a deep hierarchy. The database is already filled with over a million rows. And if I try to insert a new array the MySQL immediately runs on 100% CPU and needs about 20 minutes to insert that new structure into the database.

The reason is because it needs to calculate LEFT and RIGHT for nested set considering already existent data in the table.

Is there a more efficient way to insert such hierarchies into the database?

Comment: I suspect that the routines you are using are inserting records, then updating the LEFT and RIGHT values in the database as further records are inserting. Leading to a massive number of SQL statements. If so then calculating the LEFT and RIGHT in advance within PHP (recursive routines to loop down through the tree structure, passing the structure and the number by reference) would likely be far more efficient.

Comment: @Kickstart Hm, but if I calculate LEFT and RIGHT beforehand (when building the array) I have to do the same queries to read/calculate them as when I am reading the array and calculating LEFT and RIGHT then.

Comment: I do not know Laravel (but have used nested sets). You might have to extend the functionality to do this. But using a recursive function you should be able to do it with minimal calculations. Just counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example of adding the left and right items to the various arrays (assuming that the lowest level of the arrays is a row of items, so no need add a left and right to these individual items).

Something like this could be used to add the values

```
<?php 

  function array_left_right (&$array, &$counter = 1)
  {
    if (is_array($array))
    {
      $array['left'] = $counter++;
      foreach($array as $array_key=>&$array_item)
      {
            array_left_right($array_item, $counter);
      }
      $array['right'] = $counter++;
    }
  }

  $fred = array(array(array('a', 'b'), array('c', 'd'), array('e', 'f'), array('g', 'h')),array(array('aa', 'ab'), array('ac', 'ad'), array('ae', 'af'), array('ag', 'ah')));

  array_left_right($fred);

  print_r($fred);
```

Comment: Cool! And if I have already values in the database which value do I need to add as the start counter instead of 1?

Comment: @MangoD, depends where you are adding them. But assuming you are putting them at the lowest level, set it to the existing max RIGHT, then change that existing max right to the final value of $counter.